# Lagrange Multiplier isn't working?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the following question:
If the constraint function is $g=\pi r^{2}hwu=1$ and the function is $f=4r^{2}wuh$ then using the Lagrange Multiplier system $\lambda=\frac{4}{\pi}$ for all cases. Does that mean that there is no solution or infinite solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  Your test function is a constant times your constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from $$\pi r^2hwu=1$$ we get
$$hwu=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}$$ plugging this in $f$ we obtain
$$f=\frac{4}{\pi}$$